# Arba'a Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fourteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zevulun Ben Yaakov Avinu was born on 7 Tishrei 2200 and died in the year 2314 at the age of 114 (per the Sefer "The Shevatim" by Rabbi Moshe Polter)

Answer (score 2):

114 equals "צדיק" minus "מים" equals "פרוזדור" minus "טרקלן". (Source: [*The Chosen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chosen_%28Potok_novel%29): "From this we learn that the righteous man who removes himself from Torah also removes himself from the world-to-come!")

Comment: I do hope someone comes up with a better answer than that one — or, alternatively, a real source for it.